# What's the big O Notation for the two for loops

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I am having a hard time analyzing this piece of code:

```
public int example(int[] arr){
    int n = arr.length, total = 0 ; 
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) 
        for (int j=0; j <= i; j++) 
            total += arr[j];
    return total;
}
```

These two loops don't have curly braces. I could not analyze the time complexity of them.
I need help in counting the time of operation for both of them.

Comment: A `for` or `while` or `if` without curlies will apply to the next line directly. It is a shortcut (which is typically avoided to prevent bugs).

Comment: You have to count how often `total += arr[j]` is executed. First outer loop generates `1` iteration, then `2`, then `3`, then `4`, ... up to `n` iterations. So in total `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` which is, given the sum formula, `(n^2 + n)/2` which is in `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `O(n2)`, since there are two layers of loops. The fact that there aren't curly braces does not matter.

The outer loop is executed `O(n)` times and the inner loop is executed first once, then twice, up until `n` times. This is an arithmetic sequence from `1` to `n` where the common difference is `1`. Its sum is therefore

`(1 + n) * (n) / 2`

= `(n^2 + n) / 2`

= `O(n^2)`

That code could be rewritten with curly braces as follows:

```
  for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j <= i; j++) {
         total += arr[j];
      }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but what is the counting operation time of each line of each loop. This is hard for me to count it. Like is it (n +1) and what's the next one ?

Comment: @Tasneem What do you mean?

Comment: I am trying to know the count of operation of each loop @hev1

Comment: Why did you write (n - 1) instead of  (n +1). This part I don't understand. @hev1

Answer (score 2):

First loop is executed `O(n)` times.
Nested loop is executed `O(n)` times.

So overall `O(n^2)`.